# Detecting Weak Entity

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I am studying ER diagrams and I came across a question about a **BANK** miniworld.

The question says:

1. For each payment for a loan, bank maintains the date and amount of payment.
2. Each loan payment is associated with particular loan and is identified by a payment number, unique among the payments for that loan.

I think that payment entity should be strong (regular) entity. It has unique key. However, answer says it is **weak entity**.

How can decide whether the entity weak or regular (strong) in this case?

Comment: "unique amount the payments for that loan" isn't a grammatically valid phrase or sentence. Please correct or explain what you mean.

Comment: It was a typo. It should be among.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. In that case, I agree that it's a weak entity set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the payment number alone uniquely identifies each payment, then it's a regular entity set. If the payment number is an ordinal number or value that only distinguishes between different payments of the same loan, then it's a weak entity set.

For example, a regular entity relation would have rows like this:

```
payment_number | loan_number |    date    |  amount
      1        |     123     | 2018-01-01 |  1000.00
      2        |     123     | 2018-02-01 |  1010.00
      3        |     200     | 2018-01-02 |   500.00
      4        |     200     | 2018-02-02 |   550.00
```

As you can see, the `payment_number` by itself is uniquely identifying.

A weak entity relation could have rows like this:

```
loan_number | payment_number |    date    |  amount
    123     |       1        | 2018-01-01 |  1000.00
    123     |       2        | 2018-02-01 |  1010.00
    200     |       1        | 2018-01-02 |   500.00
    200     |       2        | 2018-02-02 |   550.00
```

In this case, the `payment_number` by itself isn't sufficient to identify each row, we have to use the combination of `(loan_number, payment_number)`.

Comment: Your second example explains the sentence "unique among the payments for that loan". It makes sense. Thank you.